# Create a branch from past commits and don't include new commits

Tags: git, github

I accidentally merged to the main, so now I need to create a branch from a past commit before the new one and assign this new branch as my new main. How can I do this?

I've tried creating it using `git checkout -b new-main hash` but it didn't work.  If i check the  log the past commit was the last one, but the code and files weren't removed.

Comment: _but the code and files weren't removed_ Checking out a new branch does **not** remove files that aren't under version control.  And you wouldn't want it to!

Comment: but if I'm 100% sure I need it no more, what can I do to create a new branch or reset the changes and remove them from the version control?

Comment: After checking out the new branch, `git status` should report the unwanted files as not being under version control.  If you're certain they are safely checked in to the main branch, you can just remove them.